# Regex to extract lang and country from bundle name

Tags: java, regex

I use Java 7.

I would like to extract the lang and the country from a String which represent a bundle file name or properties file name. File name doesn't contains the extension.

For example

- bundle --> Empty string or null
- bundle_en --> en
- bundle_en_US --> en_US
- complicated_bundle_name_en_US --> en_US

I tried this but it doesn't give me the expected result.

```
private static void testPattern(String bundleName) {
        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+(_[a-z]{2,3}(_[A-Z]{2,3}){0,1}){0,1}");
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(bundleName);
        if (matcher.matches()) {
            for (int i = 0; i < matcher.groupCount(); ++i) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i  + " = " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Nothing");
        }
    }
```

For "bundle_en_US" its show:

> Group 0 = bundle_fr_US 
>   Group 1 = null

Can you help me to correct my regex or may be this regex already exist in the java core ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem is imo that `.+` in the beginning already matches the whole sequence. Use reluctant quantifier instead:

```
.+?(_[a-z]{2,3}(_[A-Z]{2,3}){0,1}){0,1}
```

Edit: The finest solution I would consider this:

```
.+?(?:_([a-z]{2,3})(?:_([A-Z]{2,3}))?)?
```

Using non capturing groups this solely captures language and country code and throws out the "_". Additionally you should change your `for` condition to `i <= matcher.groupCount()` otherwise you miss the last group. Using the last version and the altered for condition you get:

Input: `bundle`
Output:

```
Group 0 = bundle
Group 1 = null
Group 2 = null
```

Input: `bundle_en`
Output:

```
Group 0 = bundle_en
Group 1 = en
Group 2 = null
```

Input: `bundle_en_US`
Output:

```
Group 0 = bundle_en_US
Group 1 = en
Group 2 = US
```

Comment: Man, you're right! Good job :) But maybe you could consider this one instead of yours: `.+?(_([a-z]{2,3})(_([A-Z]{2,3}))?)?` ([example](http://fiddle.re/0b4j)).

Comment: Yes, of course, if you want to match language and country code directly that's even better.

Comment: @spOOm: Altered your's a bit more and added it to the post. +1 for your suggestion.

Comment: @lost What is the use of '?' in the regex?

Comment: @LaChamelle See the docs of `Pattern`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html `+?` is the reluctant version of the greedy `+` and `(?:` starts a non-capturing group where `(` starts a capturing. Non-capturing groups don't appear as groups in the matcher. Ah yes, and the `?` alone is an equivalent to `{0,1}`.

Comment: @lost Ok, i would like to match the basename, how do I capture the group ? I tried `"(.+)?(?:_([a-z]{2,3})(?:_([A-Z]{2,3}))?)?"` but failed. Is is possible to match the lang and the country in the same group ?

Comment: `(.+?)(?:_([a-z]{2,3}(?:_[A-Z]{2,3})?))?` gives you base name in group 1 and language + optionally country in group 2 (group 2 without leading underscore). Some voting / acceptance is appreciated btw as the original question has been answered already.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
     final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+_([a-z]{2,3}(_[A-Z]{2,3})?)?");
```